# Why does Blue Origin claim Virgin Galactic's spaceplane doesn’t have an escape system whereas Virgin Galactic's passengers are wearing parachutes?

Tags: safety, sub-orbital, parachute, blue-origin, virgin-galactic

https://twitter.com/blueorigin/status/1413521631717122059 ([mirror](https://archive.ph/KsL5m)):

[image]

vs. https://space.stackexchange.com/a/54072/1111 by [John Thomas](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/42344/john-thomas):

> [Virgin Galactic's passengers] do appear to be wearing parachutes.

Comment: Did they mention the price difference anywhere as well? Because they simply don't offer the same service.

Comment: You don't have parachutes in regular air-planes; surely any escape route/device mainly serves the purpose of giving passengers false peace of mind.

Comment: You want to jump next to a burning rocket motor??  To date every actual use of a launch escape system has involved situations where jumping would be suicide.

Comment: they also claim it's not a rocket... It's in fact an aircraft shaped rocket just like the Space Shuttle was.

Comment: @JonathanReez the first civilian flight was last week.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

First of all, it should be clear that this infographic is by no means objective; it's designed to put SS2 in the worst possible light, and New Shepard in the best.

That said, an ["escape system" in the rocket launch context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launch_escape_system) normally means an automatic rocket-powered system which takes the crew capsule rapidly away from a malfunctioning or exploding booster.

In SS2, where the crew compartment and the rocket motor are integrally combined in one fuselage, there's no way for the crew to get away from the motor. The parachutes might save a crew if the airframe fails on the way down, after the rocket motor has burned out completely, but otherwise, they're not very useful as a safety measure.

Comment: Speaking of "getting away from the motor" --- in New Shepard they are literally sitting right beside the escape SRM.  https://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/escapemotor.jpg

Comment: Clearly they need secondary escape motors to get away from the escape motor!

Comment: We have an example of the parachutes in use, unfortunately. Peter Siebold and Michael Alsbury were the pilot and copilot on VSS Enterprise's last flight. Siebold managed to unstrap himself from his seat after it fell free from the breaking up aircraft, and his parachute deployed automatically after he lost consciousness, but Alsbury's remains were found still strapped into his seat in the wreckage. For much of the flight, you can't realistically expect to escape the vehicle if things go wrong, and even if you manage that you're unlikely to get out uninjured.

Comment: Per WP, "On November 7, Siebold told investigators that the aircraft broke up around him. He was still strapped into his seat. He released the straps and his parachute later deployed automatically."

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Siebold#SpaceShipTwo_VSS_Enterprise_crash also details some of his injuries. His exit from the vehicle was not an easy or gentle one.

Comment: I wonder if Virgin chose a hybrid motor for safety reasons. It can be shut down unlike a solid engine, and yet isn't prone to cause a fiery explosion when fuel and oxidiser of a liquid engine mix. So _getting away from the motor_ is perhaps not as critical for SS2 as it is for New Shepard.

Comment: Being pressure-fed gives the hybrid some relatively dangerous failure modes, especially since high pressure nitrous oxide can explosively decompose...see Mythbusters for the sort of damage a high pressure tank can cause even with fully inert gas. A breaking up liquid-fueled rocket is fiery, but not especially destructive...an example being CRS-7, where the Dragon survived the vehicle breakup despite not having an abort system and could have been recovered had its parachutes been triggered.

Comment: Does a spaceplane need a launch escape system? Unlike rockets, it can glide back to the ground. Notably the space shuttle didn't have an escape system beyond detaching the orbiter and gliding to the surface.

Comment: Gliding to the surface has nothing to do with it. The two Shuttle failures and the VSS Enterprise failure all rendered the vehicle unable to do so. The Shuttle is in fact no longer used because it was too unsafe. What a vehicle needs to operate without a LES is reliability, being airplane-shaped doesn't give you that.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff: I make a point on that dragon failure does not count as LoV on a hypothetical crewed mission because the crew would have been able to pull the chutes.

Comment: I'd just want to remind everyone regarding escape systems on airplanes: about all fighter jets have very efficient escape systems.

Answer (score 9):

Because this isn't an informational infographic. This is an *ad*. And, as such, it is deliberately skewed to paint the advertised product in the best possible light, while disparaging the competing product(s) as much as possible.

As mentioned in the other answer, Virgin Galactic doesn't have a "[Launch Escape System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launch_escape_system)" It *does* have other safety systems in the event of an emergency , but there's nothing that requires Blue Origin to tell people about their competitor's products. [Lying by omission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie#Lying_by_omission) is one of the most common, if not *the* most common, lies that advertisers use.

Comment: Interesting that they believe there is enough of a market for this service that it's worth putting out advertising for it.  I mean, of course there's a market in that a lot of people who would want to do it, but how many could *afford* it at this point?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Yeah, I don't know who they were targeting. Maybe their marketing department just wanted to keep in practice?

Comment: @HiddenWindshield maybe the FAA and they're hoping Virgin's launch license gets pulled?

Comment: This industry is rapidly growing, it does not hurt to plan for the near future when prices won't be so high.

Comment: @eps Good point.